# Specifying how many numbers there can be in an argument

Tags: r

Apologies in advance if this a stupidly easy question that's already on here somewhere. Im doing an assignment for my programming course for R. For one of the questions of our assignment, our professor has asked us to make a certain function. Two validity statements he wants us to add to our function are "Stop the execution and print an appropriate error message if the argument is not numeric or it contains more than one number."

I know how to test the validity for the former, I have no idea how to test the validity of the latter. The argument is supposed to be only one, numerical element.

Comment: Check the `length` of your numeric input. It should be 1.

Comment: @deschen This is what I put :    if(length(a)!= 1)
                                                    stop(Error:"This contains more than one number")              When I run the function and put a vector in as "a", the error check does not show up.

Comment: @deschen Got it to work after fixing my syntax. Thank you for your help! You saved me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two logical tests `is.numeric(x)` and `length(x) == 1` with a boolean AND (using the `&` symbol).

For example, the following function should give the correct responses:

```r
f <- function(x) {
   if(!(is.numeric(x) & length(x) == 1)) {
      stop(paste(x, collapse = ","), " is not a single number")
   }
   cat(x, "is a single number")
}
```

Let's test it out with different inputs:

```
f(1)
#> 1 is a single number

f(c(1, 2))
#> Error in f(c(1, 2)): 1,2 is not a single number

f("a")
#> Error in f("a"): a is not a single number

x <- 1:3

f(x)
#> Error in f(x): 1,2,3 is not a single number

f(x[3])
#> 3 is a single number
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I did not even think of using & for this. Thank you for making my code more efficient.